# shutil.move if directory already exists

Tags: python

I have a code that I am using to move all jpg files from source to destination. First time the code runs fine and it moves the files but if I run it again, it gives an error that the file already exists.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/Downloads/direc.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.move(jpg, dst_pics)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 542, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Users/tom/Downloads/Dest/Pictures/Photo3.jpg' already exists
```

Here is my code

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

local_src = '/Users/tom/Downloads/'
destination = 'Dest'

src = local_src + destination
dst_pics = src + '/Pictures/'

print(dst_pics)

for pic in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.jpg")):
    if os.path.isfile(pic):
        if not (os.path.isfile(dst_pics + pic)):
            shutil.move(pic, dst_pics)
        else:
            print("File exists")
```

Is there anything that I can do so it can overwrite the file or checks to see if the file exists and skip it?

I was able to solve it by following @Justas G solution.

**Here is the solution**

```
for pic in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.jpg")):
    if os.path.isfile(pic):
        shutil.copy2(pic, dst_pics)
        os.remove(pic)
```

Comment: I already tried that solution but it didn't work. It doesn't overwrite the file even after using full path.

Comment: Did you try to do a `if os.path.exists(dir):` check and then `shutil.rmtree(dir)` if it exists? At that point you should be able to write to that path. You can perform similar actions using the pathlib module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use copy insted of move, it should overwrite files automatically

`shutil.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath)`

Then of course you need to delete original files. Be aware, `shutil.copy` does not copy or create directories, so you need to make sure they exist.

If this does not work either, you can manually check if file exists, remove it, and move new file:

To check that file exists, use:

`from pathlib import Path
my_file = Path("/path/to/file")`

`if my_file.exists():` to check that something at path exist

`if my_file.is_dir():` to check if directory exists

`if my_file.is_file():` to check if file exists

To delete directory with all its contents use:
`shutil.rmtree(path)`

Or delete a single file with
`os.remove(path)` and then move them one by one

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by following your instructions. See my edit above.

Comment: Happy to help ^^

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the code above I move folder into already existing directories and this collision will produce an error so I recommend `shutil.copytree()`

```py
shutil.copytree('path_to/start/folder', 'path_to/destination/folder', dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

The `dirs_exist_ok=True` is required to allow overwriting files, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: This works only in Python 3.8 or later